# Can't connect to database but no error from database

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker

I have few microservices that uses one database, laravel and java,everything is served by docker.
Yesterday everything was fine, but today without any change in code or system nothing can use database. 
I can connect do database in DBeaver and everything is how it should.
Every microservice failing to timeout expired, I trying to fix it for almost 4 hours and don't have any idea left what can be wrong.
Anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

### Errors:

Laravel app connect's to db (tried to change data like host or port and then error was instant without any timeouts), but after first attempt to use it doesn't get response.

In db logs nothing, only that ones from dbeaver.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: insert into "oauth_clients" ("user_id", "name", "secret", "provider", "redirect", "personal_access_client", "password_client", "revoked", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, Docker_Laravel Personal Access Client, cfwun6QVegsGWm7rqRdguVuPUs5YcXFLtq1VubZY, ?, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 2021-08-27 09:55:14, 2021-08-27 09:55:14) returning "id")

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|
```

database throws no error, and connection setting are correct, nothing was changed everything is on same HEAD which worked before.

#### Edit

I also should mention that laravel connect's with db through docker and when I changed host and port to the same as in dbeaver(which worked) laravel api didn't connect at all.

##### Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: name_db
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: db_dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5431:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ---
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ---
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 50m
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
  
  user_api:
    container_name: name_api
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./docker/user_api
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      - ./user_api:/var/www/app
```

Comment: `It connects`... are you sure? Because you've shown us an error message which says `The connection attempt failed`.

Comment: `nothing can use database`...are you sure the database service is still running?

Comment: Yes it does, i can edit, see and insert in dbeaver. About connection I meant that when I changed connection data error showup instantly and there was no timeout but just connection attempt failed.

Comment: Ok. That was really not clear, you should edit the question to add a clearer explanation of how you generated each error

Comment: If you're getting timeouts while running queries then maybe the service is overloaded with too many connections, or the queries are inefficient, or there's a network issue, or a combination of all those perhaps. Have you tried simply restarting the DB service?

Comment: Yes I did restart all docker images few times, tried to run only one service with db.

Comment: It could be a networking issue between the laravel container and the database container. Can you post a snippet how do you start the docker containers?

Comment: sure, I did. But how could it change between pc shut down and turn on?

Comment: Restarting the PC should not actually have any effect on the docker-compose setup. Which hostname & port do you use within your laravel app?

Comment: i use db and 5431 but actually i found sollution

Comment: Great that you found a solution; Attention within the container network the internal ports of the services should be used -> in your case 5432;
Port 5431 is mapped to your host and should not be available within the container network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually deleting all junk from docker

Updatig all aps

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

And rebooting computer fixed it